# Firebase Cloud Firestore Throws "Unknown Error" If I pause upload later than 400ms after upload started

Tags: reactjs, firebase-storage

I am trying out firebase for the time and I wrote a code to try out the cloud storage service, but I realized that if I pause the file upload later than 400 - 500ms after I started it, it throws an unknown error. Here is my code

```
async function uploadFile() {
    //file comes from a file a file input html element
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(ref(cloudStorage, `videos/${file.name}`),file);

    uploadTask.on("state_changed",(snapshot) => {
        const uploadProgress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            
        //I update a state
        setProgress(Math.floor(uploadPercent));

    switch (snapshot.state) {
    case "paused":
        console.log("Upload paused");
    break;
    case "running":
        console.log("Upload resumed");
    break;
    }
},
(e) => {
    console.log("an error occurred...", e.serverResponse, e);
 },
() => {
    console.log("upload completed!");
     });

    setTimeout(() => {
    uploadTask.pause();
    }, 400); 
     //result => download is paused with no error

    setTimeout(() => {
    uploadTask.pause();
    }, 500); 
    //result => unknown error occurred

}
```

Error stack...

```
    an error occurred... <empty string> FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response. (storage/unknown)
    FirebaseError errors.ts:85
    StorageError error.ts:40
    unknown error.ts:126
    backoffDone request.ts:163
    triggerCallback backoff.ts:67
    responseHandler backoff.ts:91
    node_modules bundle.js:45348
    promise callback*doTheRequest request.ts:113
    node_modules bundle.js:45038
    setTimeout handler*callWithDelay backoff.ts:72
    start backoff.ts:136
    start_ request.ts:184
    node_modules bundle.js:45309
    NetworkRequest request.ts:76
    makeRequest request.ts:273
    _makeRequest service.ts:309
    node_modules bundle.js:47029
    node_modules bundle.js:46971
    promise callback*_resolveToken task.ts:211
    _continueUpload task.ts:296
    node_modules bundle.js:46956
    setTimeout handler*_start task.ts:195
    completeTransitions_ task.ts:477
    node_modules bundle.js:46992
    promise callback*./node_modules/ bundle.js:46988
    node_modules bundle.js:46971
    promise callback*_resolveToken task.ts:211
    _createResumable task.ts:233
    _start task.ts:186
    node_modules bundle.js:46919
    UploadTask task.ts:156
    uploadBytesResumable$1 reference.ts:291
    uploadBytesResumable api.ts:167
    initiateTransaction TimeStampTest.js:12
    React 23
    js index.js:7
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack3

    TimeStampTest.js:40

​
```

upload is working fine the error comes when I try to pause the operation,
I would appreciate it if anyone can show me a way out of this...

Answer (score 0):

try update firebase to most recent version:

```
npm install firebase@9.15.0-canary.3ee35f9ae
```

recently paused bugs were found and fixed, but not yet released in the stable version.